# How to reset the autoincrement field in Mysql data base?

Tags: mysql

How to reset the autoincrement field in Mysql data base?

Comment: If you want more answer, specify _why_ you want to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the auto-increment column by using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 10;
```

You can retrieve the most recent automatically generated `AUTO_INCREMENT` value with the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` SQL function.

If you wish to set auto-increment value to be 1, you can also truncate the table data.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
```

I hope this answer will help you. Thanks.